# Difficulty positioning centered div (again)

Tags: html, css, position

http://samnorris.co.nz/backup/test/

In the section with the Pythagoras quote "There is geometry in the humming of the strings,
there is music in the spacing of the spheres" is a little experiment from Codepen I've tweaked a bit and have been playing around with (the rotating animated circles)

...not sure if my mind is just working a bit slow tonight or what but I'm having a great amount of difficulty positioning and centering the div that contains these elements underneath the div's that contain the quote and without overlaying the background...

any help would be appreciated :)

edit: updated code, I figured out why it was being pushed down (padding on the wrapper was causing it, so I've changed the background div to fixed height instead) now I just need to figure out why I am having to use left: 32% (roughly) to try and center it. Margin: 0 auto is failing me, and setting #spheres-block to width 100% messes up the bg.

**Relevant CSS**:

```
.spacesuit-bg {
    background: transparent url("../img/spacesuit-bg.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;   
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15% 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);  
}


.quote-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 300px;

}

.quote-one {
    font: 18px/1em "proxima_nova_rgbold", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);   
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: .06em;            
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

.quote-two {
    font: 36px/1em "proxima_nova_rgbold", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);   
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: .06em;            
    width: 90%;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.spacesuit-wrapper:before, .missiongo, .golaunch { 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
}


#spheres-block {
  overflow: hidden;     
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  left: 32%;
}

.spheres {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:absolute;
}

.rings {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255, .5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.6  
}
```

**Relevant HTML**:

```
<div id="spacesuit-bg" class="section spacesuit-bg">
 <div id="spheres-block">
  <div class="spheres">
  <div class="rings"></div>
  <div class="rings"></div>
  <div class="rings"></div>
  <div class="rings"></div>  
  <div class="rings"></div>  
  <div class="rings"></div>     
</div>
</div>
 <div class="quote-wrapper">
   <div class="quote-one wow flipInX">"There is geometry in the humming of the strings,</div>
   <div class="quote-two wow flipInX">there is music in the spacing of the spheres."</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the quote appear over the rings and not beneath them?

Comment: Off topic but, Nice Website. :)

Comment: I would like it layered directly behind the quote with the quote over it... changing #spheres-block to absolute position puts it above the quote block-style, but that's not what I want :)

Comment: @Wesley - dude, thanks! my first positive comment on it (from someone I don't personally know, that is) haha, means a lot :D cheers, almost got it finished...few things left to do still.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a CSS expert (trying to learn, that's why I spend time here :)), so I may have missed other issues with my suggestion, but anyway I was able to achieve the desired effect by positioning the `speres-block` relatively, and positioning the `quote-wrapper` absolutely with a top offset of 0:

```css
#spheres-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.quote-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

I hope I understood correctly.

[image]